# Get corner points from polygon defined by linear equations

Tags: math, linear-algebra

Let's say we have a list of n equations `m * x = b`

I want to get all corner points of the polygon which has the x, y axis and the straigh lines as a bounding box.

The red circles in the picture below shows the points I want.

How can I get them if I have a list of tuples `(m, b)`?

*Time complexity does not matter*

[image: red points show which points I want]

Comment: This looks much like a *linear programming* problem to me ... your search engine should be your next port of call if you are not familiar with the term or the computational approach.

Comment: Thanks. Inlucded "linear programming" in my search and instantly get a result!

Comment: My question already has an anweser here: https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/4540/how-to-find-all-vertices-of-a-polyhedron